# How to add multiple IDs in This Script [ need syntax ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I have the below script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                if ($('#wrapper').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
                    document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
                }
            }, 3000)
        })
        //]]>
</script>
```

You see there is only used **#wrapper** and i want to add more two ids two **#footer** and **#sidebar**

**Attention:** i can create separate javscript for each id, but that is memory consumer, heavy pageload, and lot of javascripts.

so thats i want to ask, if there is any way to add multiple ids in that script, please share with my two ids i given. thanks.

Comment: What is the desired result?  Are you trying to do a logical and or a logical or?

Comment: Hi, @Taplar yes, i want to to it with logical OR. means if any if these ID #wrapper or #footer or #sidebar have visibility:hidden then the page should be redirected...please share full code..thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can include [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in a single call to jQuery:

```
$('#wrapper, #footer, #sidebar')
```

**However**, the resulting call to `.css()` will only return the first element in the result set.  But you can call `.each()` on the result set just as easily:

```
$('#wrapper, #footer, #sidebar').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
});
```

Or maybe even something like this:

```
var elements = $('#wrapper, #footer, #sidebar');

setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ($(elements[i]).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
        }
    }
}, 3000)
```

That way you don't need to re-query the DOM every time (unless you expect those elements to change).

Comment: please share the full code @David i tried but nothing happened, how can i use it in that script like this .css('visibility') == 'hidden' means three of them == to hidden. how to assign these two ids too.

Comment: @bradly: I've made some more updates to the answer.  Admittedly, I didn't notice the call to `.css()` at first, and that wouldn't work with more than one resulting matched element.  But you can treat the resulting matched elements like an array.

Comment: Thanks Bundles @David only your's both code worked perfect for me...for page load i only just add $(document).ready(function() {
. thanks for your time and great work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var ids= ["#wrapper", "#footer", "#sidebar"];
for (var i = 0 ; i < ids.length ; i++) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if ($(ids[i]).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
                document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
            }
        }, 3000)
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, @remdevtec the code given by #David worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //if any of them are hidden, do your stuff
    if ($('#wrapper, #body, #sidebar').filter(':hidden').length > 0) {
        document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your time @Taplar however, your code does not work, i was looking for .css not filter....anyhow the code shared by #David worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I haven't used visibility much.